# Is it possible to upload binary file attachments (AttachedContentDocument) to records using the REST APIs?

Tags: rest-api, attachment, upload

I'm trying to programmatically upload a file (AttachedContentDocument) to an Account as an attachment using the REST API. This doesn't seem to be documented by Salesforce.

When I use the Lightning UI to upload the file on the "Documents" tab of an account, the URL it opens is `/lightning/r/AttachedContentDocument/id...` so I'm trying to upload a `AttachedContentDocument`.

I'm crafting a request body that looks like:

```
--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_attachedcontentdocument";
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "Title": "hello",
   "FileExtension": "png"
}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/png
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Body"; filename="myfile.png"

... binary data of file ....
```

All of the examples online for inserting files into salesforce use this multipart body. Note I changed the name to `name="entity_attachedcontentdocument"` to reflect the sObject type being inserted. Then I craft a request:

> curl https://mydomain.salesforce.com/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/AttachedContentDocument/ -H 'Authorization: ...' -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="boundary_string"" --data-binary @binaryjson

This errors with:

```
[{"message":"Invalid field: 'Body'","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]
```

Looking at the [`AttachedContentDocument` documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_AttachedContentDocument.htm) there's no documentation on which field data is supposed to go into.

I get the same error changing the endpoint and entity name to `/ContentDocument/`. And no field name seems to work, not Body/Content/File.

Is it possible to use this API?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_AttachedContentDocument.htm) you linked states:

> This read-only object contains all ContentDocument objects associated with an object.
>
> For more information, see AttachedContentDocument in the Object Reference for Salesforce and Lightning Platform.

If you go [there](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_attachedcontentdocument.htm), it says:

> Use this object to list all ContentDocument objects attached to an object via a feed post.
>
> To retrieve ContentDocument objects, issue a describe call on an object, which returns a query result for each activity since the record was created. You can’t directly query this object.

So, you actually need a [FeedItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm), which has superseded the old FeedPost object. The fields you need will be found in the documentation for FeedItem.

Comment: I'm confused. I'm trying to upload a file and attach it to a user account. I don't think i want a FeedItem? I may have found a way to do this with ContentVersion and i'm asking a new question

Comment: @AndyRay Oh, your question just said "Account", so I thought you meant the CRM object. Still, according to the docs, you can attach files to a User this way.